# Cartalyst Sentinel get all roles

Tags: php, cartalyst-sentinel

So I have chosen Sentinel as an ACL for my CMS. And I'm getting to the point where I need to assign roles to users. To do that I need to get a list of all available roles. But when requesting:

```
Role::all()
```

from my model (which extends the EloquentRole) I only get id's. While an id is a good start I'm going to need more. Preferably:

```
Role::pluck('id', 'slug', 'name')
```

I have searched high and low for a way to get this. But neither the documentation nor the world seem to utter a word on this.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To get all available roles as array:

```
$roles = Sentinel::getRoleRepository()->all();
```

Or, if you need Eloquent(Role) objects:

```
$roles = DB::table('roles')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I was in a bit of an eloquent flow. It seems

```
Role::all()
Role::pluck(...)
```

Indeed do not work. But a regular:

```
Role::get()
```

does. Whoopsie

Answer (score 0):

There's `getRoles()` function in

```
cartalyst/sentinel/src/Roles/RoleableInterface.php
```

You can use it with `\Sentinel::getRoles()` in Laravel.

This one might be more simple.

```
$roles = Sentinel::getRoleRepository()->get();
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        echo $role->name."<br/>";
    }
```